# How to sum field values with matching IDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to sum multiple values in the same field based on a table id. The code below works however, it produces duplicates. The field "p.AAAPieces" has multiple values for a table ID, often many are 0. In the case below for pro 14120806, the total for all lines is 2 not 2 for each line. I need this as one line. I have tried 'DISTINCT' with no success. Thanks for any help.

```
SELECT a.AAAREFNUMVALUE AS "Pro Number",
a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE AS "Table ID",
a.AAAREFNUMTYPE AS "Number Type",
d.AAADB2Date AS "Pickup Date",


(SELECT SUM (p.AAAPIECES)
FROM dbo.AAATRANSPORTLINE p 
WHERE p.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE
GROUP BY p.AAATRANSPORTTABLE
)

AS "Total Pieces",

(SELECT TOP 1 a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE
FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a2
WHERE a2.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND
a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 2 
ORDER BY a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE ASC
) AS "Shippers BL#"

FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATODATES d ON a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE 
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATRANSPORTLINE p ON  a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = 
p.AAATRANSPORTTABLE
WHERE AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1 AND D.AAADATETYPE = 1;
```

This is a sample result I get:

```
pro#        table id  #type    date          total pcs
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
```

I need this, but summed on 1 line:

```
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          2
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          0
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          0
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          0
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          0
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          0
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          0
14120806    5637146076  1   2019-04-10          0
```

Comment: This is an unusual query method. I think you could greatly simplify your query - and eliminate the duplicates if you use `LEFT JOIN` clauses instead of all the subqueries. Perhaps if you can show your data schema, it would be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: 1) I am pretty sure that @daShier 's re-factoring suggestion is the way to go, with the GROUP BY from the re-factored sub-query 1 being moved to end of the new version of the whole query, and TOP+ORDER BY from the re-factored sub-query 2 being replaced my MAX in the new query.  2) Please clarify the purpose, original spec would be nice. 3) Replacing the Headache-Causing Crypto-Strings such as AAAXYZXSOMEWEIRDNAME with something friendly, like SomeWeirdName for the purpose of this forum may make the people who want to help you, well, want to help you more :)

Comment: use primary key to filter and sort